# file.cs on line 2: error CS0161: `testingCSharp._runbdrrr.add(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

Please, I just got started with C# and I was asked to carry out a basic task.

**Question:** Write a function that returns the sum of two numbers

Here is my code...

```
private static int sum;
int add(int param1, int param2) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter first number");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter second number");
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    sum= num1 + num2;
    Console.WriteLine("The value of your first and second number is {0}", sum);
}
```

What am i getting wrong please?

Comment: Your function `add` is expecting to return some integer variable. add `return sum;` after `Console.WriteLine("The value of your first and second number is {0}", sum);`

Comment: Thanks, works well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the method.Also you are not using input arguments.

```
 int add() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter first number");
    int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please, enter second number");
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    sum= num1 + num2;
    Console.WriteLine("The value of your first and second number is {0}", sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked well now.